# Fluid flow when x,y,z are at 0

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I'm creating a small video in which I have a glass and fluid as water to flow into the glass.

Now in my domain I do get a continuous fluid flow if I change the x,y,z direction coordinates under the domain but I get  fluid flow like water drops when x,y,z are 0.

The scene needs the flow of water directly over the glass but I don't get continuous smooth flow.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Regard,

Answer (score 2):

The x,y,z values in the fluid domain settings define the effect of gravity on the simulation. Values of 0,0,0 mean the fluid is floating in space. A Z value of -9.81 is used to approximate earths gravity.

You have a couple of options for the object used as the starting point of the fluid, setting the type to fluid gives you a single "blob" of fluid with a total volume equal to the size of the mesh while a type of inflow will give you a constant flow of fluid coming in. The initial velocity here defines the direction the fluid first moves, a negative z value will have it fall straight down, while changing the x and y values can get it to flow diagonally into your cup.

Comment: Thanks Sambler. The -ve z value is working. Thanks alot for your help.